# What is the standard definition of Torsion element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

Here are two different definitions of torsion element.

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $m\in M$.

Wikipedia: $m$ is a torsion element iff there exists a nonzero **regular** element $r$ (i.e. Not a zero divisor) such that $rm=0$.

Dummit&Foote: $m$ is a torsion element iff there exists a nonzero element $r$ such that $rm=0$.

Which one of these is the standard definition?

Comment: It might be the case Dummit and Foot stated the definition in the context of integral domains. In such case, every nonzero element is regular, and hance the definitions coincide.

Comment: for me it means the Dummit and Foote definition.

Comment: The correct definition is the one cited from Wikipedia. The second definition holds in the particular case when $R$ is a domain (usually $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: a quick search for "torsion element of a module" reveals lots of papers using it in both ways.